# How to handle the negative response of connection request in Wi-Fi direct in Android devices?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, data-connections

I am using *Wi-Fi direct* in my application. I am able to establish the connection between two Android devices.

I want to handle the *negative response* of connection request. When a User1 send connection request to User2 and if User2 denies that request, then how User1 would know that User2 denies his connection request. I have researched about this, but I couldn't able to find anything.

**Question:**

1. How to handle the negative response of connection request at senders end?

Answer (score -1):

This method you have  to define after implementing  `WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener`.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {


   if(info.groupFormed) {
        //groupformed is a boolean which will be true when user2
       // accepts the connection otherwise false.
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it won't work. It only notifies you when the initiation succeeds or fails.

Comment: then you should implement `WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener` this to listen back the state of connection.

Comment: WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener provides information if connection established, not when request denied by another device.

Comment: @The4thIceman I have seen your post on Stack overflow related to Wi-Fi direct. Can you help me with this problem?